# I possibly installed a malware by a misspelled java installation command in the terminal

Tags: apt, openjdk, malware

I was trying to download java, more specifically, JDK version 16. The right command was  `sudo apt install openjdk-16-jdk`, but I end up typing `sudo apt install open-jdk-11` instead, the funny thing is that the command ran sweet and asked me to give a confirmation if I really wanted to download the package and it gave to me a complete list of what was going to be installed, so I just typed `Y`, because who reads this sort of thing anyway?

In the middle of the installation, I noticed the command was misspelled, so I turned down the energy of my computer, so it did not finish the installation.

I tried to search on the internet if anyone already had used this command or advised someone to use it, but the only thing I found was a strange Chinese website with this command in it, which wasn't very comforting to me.

After this frustrating attempt to look for something on the web, I tried to run the same command again. Still, this time don't allow it to be installed by typing `N` when apt asked me if I really wanted it to be installed, just to see if the package was installed or not, but nothing happened. It just said to me that the package could not be found.

My question is: Could I just have installed malware, although the installation wasn't completed? Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: You couldn't install malware from Ubuntu repositories. You can run `history` and see what was the exact command.

Comment: Please add output of `apt policy open-jdk-11`. There is no such package in official repos.

Comment: *"because who reads this sort of thing anyway?"* Maybe you will from now on? 

Comment: JDK cannot contain malware anyway(Even if they managed to bypass ubuntu's virus scanners)

Answer (score 4):

The `sudo apt install openjdk-11-jdk` command installs OpenJDK Development Kit 11 in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu, however the `sudo apt install open-jdk-11`  command installs nothing and returns an `Unable to locate package open-jdk-11` error message in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu. It is likely that you installed openjdk-11-jdk and running the following command would confirm this.

```
apt policy openjdk-11-jdk
```

Another way to confirm that you unintentionally installed openjdk-11-jdk is to search through your recent bash history going back a large number of lines, let's say the last 100 lines in your bash history, for lines containing *openjdk-11-jdk*.

```
history 100 | grep openjdk-11-jdk
```

If the preceding command doesn't return any useful results, try running `history 100` without the pipe to `grep openjdk-11-jdk` in order to print all of the 100 most recent lines in your bash history.

Run the following command to uninstall openjdk-11-jdk:

```
sudo apt remove openjdk-11-jdk
```